# Large Image resizing libraries

Tags: .net, image, resize, image-manipulation

Does anyone know of any good image resizing libraries that will handling resizing large images(~7573 x ~9485).  Something that is fast and doesn't chew to much memory would be great.  At the moment I am using IrfanView and just shell invoking it with arguments but I would like to find something that integrates into .net a bit more.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) all the way.  It's a codebase with nearly every image-related operation you could possibly want to do, implemented fairly efficiently in C.  This includes various types of resizing, both interpolated (bilinear, trilinear, adaptive, etc.), and not (just decimating (sampling) or replicating pixels.  There are a ton of APIs (language bindings) that you can use in your applications, including [MagickNet](http://midimick.com/magicknet/).

Also, not sure if it's at all relevant to what you're trying to do, but I thought this was a pretty darn cool SIGGRAPH paper, so here goes: ImageMagick also supports what they call "liquid rescaling", or seam carving, a technique shown in this cool demo [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qadw0BRKeMk), and whose implementation and use in ImageMagick is discussed [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#liquid-rescale).

Answer (score 1):

A couple years ago I used [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/) in a program that needed to load some relatively big images (12-mega-pixel images). It performed really well (waaaay better than GDI+) and the API is quite simple to understand and start using. I even wrote a .NET wrapper and I think I still have it laying around somewhere, but I suppose there must be better wrappers/bindings for .NET by now.

Comment: Yep, they have a C# wrapper, thanks for pointing this out, i am going to check it out. I have been looking for a nice *small* image lib like this.

Answer (score 0):

I've used ImageMagick in the past - note that you would have to invoke it from command line, too. The good news is that it's a breeze to integrate into your project, and it's a very powerful utility.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'd go for ImageMagick definitely. I'd give http://midimick.com/magicknet/ a shot if I were you..